# Azure devops extension available icons

Tags: azure-devops

This page shows how to use an icon in Azure DevOps extensions https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-devops/components/icon

It does not however show a list of available icons or a link to one.
Where can I find which icons are available?

Update 1: It appears to be a subset of https://uifabricicons.azurewebsites.net

Update 2: rtfm, the manual says: [image: iconName in the manual]

So, we should be able to pick any icon from here: https://uifabricicons.azurewebsites.net/
However, only some (small subset) seems to work.

Comment: I guess you can put which icon you want.

Comment: well, yes, but there's a couple of predefined available icons, for example, "OpenSource" and "Video". I'd like a list with these available icons and their names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The marked solution seems incorrect. I've had a look into used font file and its content differs a bit to that on the website.

My recommendation:
Use an app able to show WOFF font files, i.e. on Windows Store the app *Character Map UWP* by Edi Wang.

With that you can just open the proper WOFF file at `node_modules/azure-devops-ui/Components/Icon/fonts/fabric-icon.woff`

That way you definitely have all supported icons and can even search through it (in case your used app supports it).

Answer (score 3):

Only ***solid*** icons from fabric icons are supported in the azure DevOps "Icon" component because you can easily apply different colors for that icon using styles.

Just search for "solid" in https://uifabricicons.azurewebsites.net/.

Answer (score -1):

In fact, we can use any image with the type: BMP, GIF, EXIF, JPG, PNG and TIFF to be a icon. The default size is 128x128 pixels. You can refer the doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/manifest?view=azure-devops#discovery-attributes.
And also you can find how to define the hole extension in this [manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/manifest?view=azure-devops) doc.

Comment: Yes, thank you I know, but there's a couple of predefined available icons, for example, "OpenSource" and "Video". I'd like a list with these available icons and their names

Comment: Hi@SeeDoubleYou, well, you are right. But in the azure devops extension, We recommend you can download that icons as the JPG file, and use it follow the guidance doc.

Comment: Well, ok. But then why are the docs here https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-devops/components/icon pointing all arrows towards using the font icons? There is a render function, but that seems more like a workaround if you read the docs: "render -- Allows for arbitrary content to be rendered instead of using an icon from
the fabric icon font. A common scenario would be rendering something like a
status icon in place of a font icon. We want to allow for scenarios that
expect iconProps to work, but still allow for custom components to be rendered."

Comment: @SeeDoubleYou Were you able to set the fabric or fluent icons as a hub icon. I can see some of the existing navigation in Azure devops uses these. But when adding my own hub, the guidance only talks about providing an image file. Guidance: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/web-navigation?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fmarketplace-extensibility%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fmarketplace-extensibility%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops#hub-icon

Comment: @Turbo, no I went with my own icon in the end